# Where/When we should use return false in php

Tags: php

I did a lot of search but couldn't find any clear guide. Please one of you experts answer my question.
Where/when we should use "return false" in an array or an if statement.
for example :

```
if(file_exists($p)) {
    // do something
} else {
    echo $error;
    return FALSE;
}
```

whole code:

```
class Base {
function __construct() {

    $url = $_GET['url'];
    $url = explode('/',$url);

    $p = $url[0].'.php';

    if(file_exists($p)) {
        require($p);
    } else {
        require('error.php');
        $error = new error();
        $error->Not_Exist();
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

Please someone explain me the reasons for use of return false.

Comment: 1) *when we should use "return false" **in an array*** How do you want to return something in an array? 2) return false when you need the code to return false ...

Comment: Please, explain, what do you mean by saying "return false in an array"

Comment: There simply is no guide nor a rule when you need to return false.

Comment: because, it doesn't exist and you need to find out why. Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Rizier123 I know that but I don't understand why it used the return false after showing the $error. Isn't showing an error enough?

Comment: @KarenV We would need to see more code to tell you why this code returns false. But this seems like you then didn't wrote this code

Comment: I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453089/in-php-does-return-false-do-anything-after-echo-statement) so does return false work same as exit in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, it only makes sense to return a value if it is potentially *going to be used*. You can return whatever you want, even if it is not going to be used, but what would be the point?

This makes sense:

```
function isOfAge($age) {
    if ($age >= 18) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
    // Shorter:
    //   return $age >= 18;
}
```

This does not make much sense:

```
function outputName($name) {
    echo "Your name is {$name}!";
    return true;
}
```

Secondly, boolean values *should* only be returned if the *result of a function* is boolean in nature, such as functions that:

- Evaluate or compare values (e.g. `isOfAge($age)`, `containsCharacter($str, $char)`, `canBeExecuted($pathToExe)`, `validDate($date)`, `sameValues($a, $b)`, etc.)
- Execute or run something and report back the result (e.g. `executeSQL($sql)`, `generateImage($data)`, `runBackgroundProcess($str)`, etc.)

You *can* also return a boolean value *only if a function fails* (or succeeds), such as:

```
function createName($first, $second) {
    if (strlen($first) === 0 || strlen($second) === 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return "{$first} {$second}";
}
```

And then you can use the return value to check if it worked, and if it did then you can be sure that it contains a string:

```
$name = createName("Sverri");
if ($name === false) {
    die("Invalid first or second name!");
} else {
    echo "Hello $name!";
}
```

That function could also be written using exceptions. Exceptions allow you to stop the script, throw an error, catch that error, and then continue the script:

```
function createName($first, $second) {
    if (strlen($first) === 0) {
        throw new \Exception("Invalid first name");
    }
    if (strlen($second) === 0) {
        throw new \Exception("Invalid second name");
    }
    return "{$first} {$second}";
}
try {
   echo createName("Sverri");
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

A good rule of thumb is to ask yourself if it *makes sense* to return a boolean value, and if the returned value is *going to be used*.

In the code in your question it would not make sense to return any value. You cannot return anything in a constructor anyway, so returning something does not make sense.

If you want to terminate a function without a return value you can just do so:

```
function uselessFunction() {
    return;
}
```

It *will* actually return a value, `null`, but when you just want to terminate a function without returning any particular value then that is how you would do it.

Comment: Thank you Sverri. I understand what does return true, but return false makes me a little confused. I don't know what does that mean at all and what happens when returning false. Does it mean to stop executing the rest of the code?

Comment: Regarding my code, if I remove the return false, a fatal error occurs. It seems it's not pointless

Comment: No, *return values* are just values that come out of functions (`true` and `false` are just values, just like strings and numbers). `return ` stops the execution of *functions*, but not of your entire script.

Comment: Thank you so much. accepted as the best answer

Answer (score 1):

I ***personally*** normally use them in `functions` to tell me if something is happening.

```
    <?php
    function isUsernameAvailable($username)
    {
        // Some db functions.

        if ($db->rowCount() == 1) return false;

        return true;
    }
    ?>
```

So if the provided username does not exist in the database then it will `return true` otherwise it will `return false`.

Usage,

```
if (isUsernameAvailable("test") == false) {
    // Username does not exist.
} else {
    // Username exists.
}
```

Comment: This is opinion based and isn't something you have to do that way.

Comment: ^^ **Exactly!**, you understood my comment completely correct and SO don't want opinion based answers! VTC -> ***primarily opinion-based**
Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.*

Comment: No it's not. 1) You said by yourself, that it is opinion based 2) You even wrote: *personally*. So there is no technical facts when you need to use `return false;`. The question is simply off-topic on SO and shouldn't be answered.